# How do I access the WSL Linux file system from Windows?

Tags: filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I found that static files served from a Rails application running in `/home/pupeno/projectx` take more or less half as much time than the ones served from `/mnt/c/Users/pupeno/projectx`. It's almost acceptable. I tried webrick and puma (as well as passenger and unicorn, which don't work yet).

So, if I'm going to host my source code in `/home/pupeno`, how do I access from Windows applications such as RubyMine?

For the record, this is the application being served from the Windows file system:

[image]

and this is the Linux file system:

[image]

Comment: By the way, don't edit any files in %localappdata%\lxss unless you know what you are doing.  Windows tools will almost always break those files.

Answer (score 19):

PM for Windows Command-Line here:

Thus far, accessing Linux files from Windows has been unsupported. To understand why, please read this post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

However, as of Windows 10 build 1903 (March 2019), we (finally!) exposed your distros' filesystems to Windows!

To learn more, please read this post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2019/02/15/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/

[image]

Look forward to hearing how you get on with this feature. If you find any problems, please file issues on the WSL GitHub repo here: https://github.com/microsoft/wsl.

Comment: LOL! Thank you Adrian. Hope you enjoy WSL's filesystem integration. We're continuing work to improve its performance and should start seeing results in the next few months as work progresses.

Answer (score 12):

With Windows 10 [version 1903 and later](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/), WSL filesystems are available in Windows via the `\\wsl$` mount. Either browse there manually or launch `explorer.exe` from a WSL path:

```sh
$ cd /home/me
$ explorer.exe .
```

If you have an existing WSL installation and you upgrade to Windows 1903 you may find that the `\\wsl$` mount doesn't work. Some users have found that [disabling and re-enabling WSL fixes the issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4027#issuecomment-495816016).

In PowerShell:

```sh
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
# Reboot when prompted
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
# Reboot when prompted
```

Disabling and re-enabling WSL didn't seem to harm my existing Ubuntu installation but it's probably worth backing up anything you want to save just in case.

Answer (score 11):

WSL mounts Windows partitions under `/mnt`. For example, you can modify files in `c:\work` on the mounted Windows filesystem by referencing them as `/mnt/c/work`.

Windows apps (cmd, file manager, etc), can access files in WSL in read-only mode by prepending with `%LocalAppData%\lxss`. Copying a file from the Windows filesystem to the WSL directories renders it unreadable, with a cryptic `general I/O error`. Files created in `%LocalAppData%\lxss` from Windows are not visible to WSL. Files created from WSL can be modified in Windows, and the modified file can subsequently be accessed by WSL.

Comment: "Files created from WSL can be modified in Windows, and the modified file can subsequently be accessed by WSL." << I would be **very** careful with that. Depending on the program you use, it may cause a mess - for example if your editor doesn't write the file in-place but creates a copy and renames it, like some do. In general, it would be advisable to stick to the rule written in large red letters here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/ - To access the WSL root from Windows, you can use local SSH and Win-SSHFS.

Comment: Not relevant anymore since Windows 10 version 1903. See the answer by chris below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59226195/7558731.

Answer (score 10):

On Windows 10 Creators Update, I use SFTP NetDrive to mount the WSL filesystem into windows as as a network drive.

There are some Window sshFS ports that'll achieve the same thing.

You'll need to start the ssh daemon via `sudo service ssh start`.

Comment: Great! I have been looking for a way to edit Linux files with a Windows app (VS code), ssh + SFTP NetDrive seems to be able to solve my problem. I will try it after going home, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

fire the CLI command **explorer.exe \\wsl$** in Windows powershell/cmd

Answer (score 1):

You can easily access, read and write files from  WSL Linux file system to Windows and vice-versa by simply navigating to the file location :

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs

Hope this helped you!!

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted twice - it is definitely one way to access files in the WSL mount from explorer

Comment: This answer should be ignored/deleted as it directly contravenes the WSL Team's guidance re. [not spelunking through the Windows filesystem to access WSL distros' files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/). Doing so may well result in data/file corruption or loss.

Comment: Yes, the files shouldn't accessed **from Windows**. But I have dual OS (Ubuntu and Windows) and I was looking for a way to copy files from WSL to Ubuntu and this answer helped me to do that.

Comment: @RichTurner What if there is no Windows, just the files? Of course this is the right answer for that case. But the format has changed from `rootfs` to `ext4.vhdx`, which should be safer to access properly, though more difficult.

Comment: @piojo - I don't follow what you're saying: While WSL2 does store its distro's filesystems in VHDX's, in order to avoid potential filesystem access collisions, it's very much advised that you access the files via the built-in filesystem redirector \\wsl.localhost\<distro>\...

Comment: @RichTurner That's an unsuitable method for getting files off a spare hard drive. That is only applicable to a working, running installation of WSL.

Comment: @piojo - The question being asked is "How do I access the WSL Linux file system from Windows", not how to access files on spare hard drives. External hard drives can be mounted and accessed as per the WSL documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk

Comment: @RichTurner What difference does it make where the filesystem comes from? If the data arrives on a floppy disk there should still be a way to access them. Also, that documentation (the VHD section) is the closest thing to a complete right answer, but it only applies to Windows 11 (or some rare versions of WSL if you were lucky enough to install it on Windows 10 before the update was pulled).

Comment: It matters a lot because to access an EXTn formatted volume, you have to mount the volume on a WSL distro instance. You then access the mounted drive via the WSL <-> Windows filesystem integration: More info here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/a-deep-dive-into-how-wsl-allows-windows-to-access-linux-files/

Answer (score 1):

\wsl$ mount point did not work for me so well, it has multiple issues, and many Windows applications fail because they see it as a network drive. For my usecase, it is [Rclone](https://rclone.org/downloads/) what helped to solve the problem to properly mount Linux filesystem so it behaves without any issues, practically the same way as a local disk.

It is free and open source. It works with sftp remote filesystems (like sshfs), so it can mount network drives both on Linux and Windows (running sshd service).

Example command how to run it, assuming remote point "server" is already configured and rclone.exe is in PATH environment variable:

```
rclone mount server:/ Z: --file-perms=0777 --track-renames --track-renames-strategy=modtime,leaf --metadata --vfs-cache-mode=full --sftp-disable-hashcheck --volname drive_name
```

For the first time, you need to configure new remote point by running:

```
rclone config
```

To find out location of the config file you have just created, run:

```
rclone config file
```

Also, you may need to install WinFsp first, if not already intalled. The best thing about it, everything just works the same way like with local disk (assuming if you provide `--vfs-cache-mode=writes` or `--vfs-cache-mode=full` option, since without it, many applications will fail to work correctly, please [read the documentation](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_serve_sftp/) to understand why). Option `--file-perms=0777` is necessary to allow running .exe files. Even though `--vfs-cache-mode=writes` may be enough for most applications, but --`vfs-cache-mode=full` is important for good performance with large files. For the same reason `--track-renames-strategy` is limited to only `modtime` and `leaf` strategies, because if other strategy is used, it will be obviously slow with large files, and `--sftp-disable-hashcheck` is necessary to prevent rclone from running md5sum, otherwise it will run it even when trying to read a file.

To register Rclone as a system service, edit and run the following command (do not run as is, please see below how you need to edit it first):

```
New-Service -Name Rclone -BinaryPathName 'C:\Program Files\Rclone\rclone.exe mount server:/ Z: --vfs-cache-mode=full --track-renames --track-renames-strategy=modtime,leaf --metadata --volname drive_name --config="C:\Program Files\Rclone\rclone.conf" --log-file="C:\Program Files\Rclone\rclone.txt" --file-perms=0777 --sftp-disable-hashcheck --no-console'
```

Obviously, you need to replace "server:/" with your actual remote point name and path, also replace drive_name with any name you like, and of cource you may need to edit paths to rclone.conf, rclone.log and rclone.exe, if you installed it in a different location.

*Note: in my case running as a system service caused some permission issues (for example, when trying to save Excel files), and I did not figured out why yet, so I ended up creating startup .bat file to run Rclone as a user, since it works perfectly this way. I will update this answer if and when I figure out how to make running as a service to work as good as running as a user.*

Even Windows software which does not like network drives, just works with RClone drives. All is needed, is to setup sshd in the remote system (which in this case is not really a remote syset, but in WSL distribution installed on the same PC). This how to setup sshd in WSL distribution: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-ssh-into-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine. And here is how to make WSL IP address static: https://github.com/ocroz/wsl2-boot, so you can have sshd running always at the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

go to filesytem and enter this location:
the operating sytem may differ, in my case it is unbuntu

```
\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\Aayana\Downloads
```